# Ionic Build or Ionic Run builds the wrong app

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework

I am trying to **build** or **run** an `Ionic Cordova` App. But it always builds a default app with playlists.

OS is Windows 10

I do the following from my command prompt:

```
c:\users\martijn\documents\ionic start testapp blank

c:\users\martijn\documents\testapp\ionic run android
```

now it is building a different app then in my app directory. When I do **ionic serve** I see the right app in my browser. Can't figure out why running or building gives me a different app, I think it is a default example app.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Try to do another name than `testapp` - could be that you have two different versions of `testapp`

Answer (score 1):

See link here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1283

Appears you may have to delete the the last apk file from `platforms\android\build\outputs\apk`